# WebSphere Integrational Developer / Eclipse Console Bug

Tags: eclipse, websphere

I'm working with WebSphere Integration Developer v6.2 (actually it is an Eclipse with a huge plugin). 
Once I had a mistake in my program and a big stacktrace was typed to the console. So that, I clicked the right button of a mouse and chose the **Clear...** menu item. It is where the problem began. Now the console is often empty except the situations when I use SVN.

Restarting, rebooting and deleting temp files chandged nothing.
If somebody knows the solution (except reinstalling =) ), please, help me!!!

Comment: Can you please show me the link to download it, thank you so much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open WID, in Business integration view go to Preferances, type console here. It will give u an option to open the SVN console. open that. here uncheck both the checkboxes. close WID and delete all log fils and then restart WID. Your problem wil b solved.

Comment: Thank you! I have solved this problem some days before now by removing subclipse plugin and reinstall the newer version of it. Your variant is much more smarter =)